# how to use crystal reort on vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

How to use crystal reort on vs 2010

1) for crystal report 2010 we have to download it from sap site and install it 
but is there any other way to do tha or any product of vs in which crystal report support is provided by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[Support for Crystal Reports for Visual Studio](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317789)

specifically looking at

> **Downloading the Crystal Reports that are compatible with Visual Studio 2010**
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 no longer includes Crystal Reports in the
>   bundle.
>
> In Visual Studio 2010, to create a Crystal Reports project or Web site
>   or to import existing projects or Web sites that were created by using
>   older versions of Visual Studio or Crystal Reports, you must first
>   install a version of Crystal Reports that is compatible with Visual
>   Studio 2010.
>
> For more information about how to use Crystal Reports in Visual Studio
>   2010, visit the following SAP Crystal Reports website:
>
> http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp